# How to automatically set the best view of the map so all markers can be displayed when map loaded?

Tags: leaflet

I have some markers in the map, How to automatically set the best view of the map so all markers can be displayed on the center when map loaded?

I try the following:

```
        var markers = [];
       
        for (let i = 0; i < geoFences.length; i++) 
        {
            var geoFenceLatLon = new L.LatLng(geoFences[i].geoFence_Lat,geoFences[i].geoFence_Lon);
            var geoFenceCircle = L.circle(geoFenceLatLon, geoFences[i].geoFence_Radius).addTo(deviceLocation);
            
            markers.push(geoFenceLatLon); //add each markers to array

            L.circleMarker([geoFences[i].geoFence_Lat, geoFences[i].geoFence_Lon], { radius: geoFences[i].geoFence_Radius });
            L.marker(geoFenceLatLon, {icon: geoFenceMarker}, { pmIgnore: true }).addTo(deviceLocation);

            if (i == geoFences.length -1)
            {
                var group = L.featureGroup(markers); //add markers array to featureGroup
                deviceLocation.fitBounds(group.getBounds());   
            }
        }

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
        }).addTo(deviceLocation);
```

but I got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.addEventParent is not a function
at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:5:69635)
at e.initialize (leaflet.js:5:68602)
at new e (leaflet.js:5:2708)
at t.featureGroup (leaflet.js:5:145305)
at renderMap
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

....
create marker(s)

//extend bounds by calling this for each marker
bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: how about if I don't have the markers, but I had some geofence circles?, how to fitBound them?

Comment: you need only positions to extend view. maybe corners from getBounds() 

var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();

Comment: var sw = geoFenceCircle.getBounds().getSouthWest();
                var ne= geoFenceCircle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
                
                var bound = new L.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
                
                bounds.push(bound);

Bounds are not valid